# We are using redshift database connection but the connection drops every two weeks and is back after jvm rest

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Redshift database connectivity issue occurs every two weeks

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Not Connected.
        at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.isConnected(Unknown Source) ~[redshift-jdbc40-1.2.16.jar:na]



Exception is java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Not Connected.
        at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.isConnected(Unknown Source) ~[redshift-jdbc40-1.2.16.jar:na]
```

Comment: HI Jon, around 2 weeks is what i mean. However, jvm restart (of my application server accessing redshift database endpoint) is fixing the issue on the spot (am able to connect post jvm restart). I suspect it being an issue with connection pooling (max connections). Can you advise.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case `connection` is remaining `idle` for long time and getting `closed`. Hence, throwing an error.

You should use following `properties` or `similar` to resolve it.

I assume that boot is configuring the DataSource for you. In this case, and since you are using MySQL, you can add the following to your application.properties up to 1.3

```
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

Explanation:

`testOnBorrow`-The indication of whether objects will be validated before being borrowed from the pool. If the object fails to validate, it will be dropped from the pool, and we will attempt to borrow another. In order to have a more efficient validation, see validationInterval. Default value is false.

`validationQuery`-The SQL query that will be used to validate connections from this pool before returning them to the caller.

Hope it helps.